# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos t^2 dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

So, I need to prove the identity

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos t^2 dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin t^2 dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

and as a hint I have the Gaussian integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-xt^2} dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} \;\;\;\forall x>0.$$

I suspect I have to take the real/imaginary part of $e^{-t^2}$ at some point, but I can't quite figure how. I.e., $\int e^z dz = e^z$ gives me nothing. So, how do I do it?

Comment: Do you know Euler's identity?

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/923588/129017)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Err, yes.

Comment: @r9m Thank you, I understand robjohn's derivation fully.

Comment: @Minethlos: you can also look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190293) for a real-variable method of evaluating this integral.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might be useful but after trying it myself I realized it was not a good hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=i$ in your hint and simplify the resulting complex number and then you need to consider real and imaginary parts of the integral. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222028/how-do-i-compute-int-infty-infty-e-fracx22t-e-ikx-mathrm) for a justification which it depends on your background.

Comment: I think it also should be explained why one could let $x=i$ when the equality really says $x>0$.

Comment: @mickep: I was about to provide him with a link that explains that but it is better to stick to the hint he was given.

Comment: The hint is meant to hold only for real $x$, yes.

Comment: @Minethlos: They want you to use the hint and I showed you how to do it.

Comment: After some research I found that they probably wanted me to use the [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) after which your advice does make sense :)

Comment: @Minethlos: Good job!

Answer (score 5):

For a nice real analytic derivation, we can notice that:
$$I^2=\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(t^2)\,dt\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\iint_{[0,+\infty)^2}\cos(s^2-t^2)\,ds\,dt = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{-v}^{v}\cos(uv)\,du\,dv$$
so:
$$ I^2 = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin v^2}{v}\,dv =\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz=\frac{\pi}{8}.$$
Some care is needed in proving that $\iint_{[0,+\infty)^2}\cos(s^2+t^2)\,ds\,dt$ vanishes and the manipulations are legit, since $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is a Riemann integrable function but it does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Beside that, this proof just mimics the proof that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ through the Fubini-Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: As I just commented to the question, I have a [real-variable approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190293). Do you have a nice real-variable method to evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: @robjohn: I usually prove it with the (inverse) Laplace transform or through the identity $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{x+n\pi}=\frac{1}{\sin x}.$$

Comment: @robjohn: in fact, we can deal with convergence issues by introducing an exponential smoothing factor $e^{-\alpha x}$ and letting $\alpha\to 0$. This gives that our approaches are essentially the same.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: that is most likely so since my approach also mimics the classic proof of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=1$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$\Im e^{iz} = \sin(z) \implies \sin(z^2) = \Im e^{iz^2}$

Comment: Yes, I know Euler's identity. But I don't see any straightforward way to use it here. Do you mean there is simpler solution than [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923525/wolfram-alpha-says-that-int-infty-infty-e-ix2dx-sqrt-frac-pii/923588#923588)?